# How to extract data from json object and json array in same POSTGRESQL query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column(name: additional_information) in the database having mode of payments recorded in Json Format like this:

**First Scenario:**

```
{
   "cash":{
      "use":1,
      "amount":"285"
   },
   "card_payment":[
      {
         "method":"Debit Card",
         "use":1,
         "amount":"5900",
         "details":"081958"
      },
      {
         "method":"Debit Card",
         "use":1,
         "amount":"3245",
         "details":"379613"
      }
   ],
   "method_title":"POS Payment"
}
```

**Second Scenario:**

```
{
   "method_title":"Cash On Delivery",
   "instructions":""
}
```

**Third Scenaario:**

```
{
   "others":[
      {
         "use":1,
         "amount":"649",
         "method":"Phonepe",
         "details":"2022040089 "
      },
      {
         "use":1,
         "amount":"59",
         "method":"Phonepe",
         "details":"T22040584749376 "
      }
   ],
   "method_title":"POS Payment"
}
```

I want to extract all the necessary info out of this
For example

cash
card
others
others_type

I have tried this:

```
 select replace(json_extract_path(sop.additional_information::json,'cash','amount')::text,'"','') AS cash,
              json_array_elements_text(json_extract_path(sop.additional_information::json,'card_payment'))::json->>'amount' AS card,
              json_array_elements_text(json_extract_path(sop.additional_information::json,'others'))::json->>'amount' AS custom,
              json_array_elements_text(json_extract_path(sop.additional_information::json,'others'))::json->>'method' AS custom_type,
              case when sop.method = 'cashondelivery' then so.grand_total::text end as cash2,
              case when sop.method = 'paytm' then so.grand_total::text end as custom2 from table sop
```

I am finding difficulty in adding all the cards value if there are more than 1 card used. I hope I explained my questions clearly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For extracting elements (keys and values) you can use `jsonb_each` function. For extracting array elements you can use `jsonb_array_elements` function. And also you can use `jsonb_typeof` for gets type of key values. For example:

```
select 
    t2.pkey,
    t2.pvalue,   
    jsonb_typeof(t2.pvalue) as valuetype 
from sample_table t1 
cross join jsonb_each(t1.json_text) t2(pkey, pvalue)
```

**Return:**

| pkey | pvalue | valuetype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cash | {"use": 1, "amount": "285"} | object |
| card_payment | [{"use": 1, "amount": "5900", "method": "Debit Card", "details": "081958"}, {"use": 1, "amount": "3245", "method": "Debit Card", "details": "379613"}] | array |
| method_title | "POS Payment" | string |
| others | [{"use": 1, "amount": "649", "method": "Phonepe", "details": "2022040089 "}, {"use": 1, "amount": "59", "method": "Phonepe", "details": "T22040584749376 "}] | array |
| method_title | "POS Payment" | string |
| instructions | "" | string |
| method_title | "Cash On Delivery" | string |

Which type of values is `array` or `object`, for these values you must use `jsonb_each` function again. But Recommended creating recursive function sub arrays and sub json's. I wrote an SQL query sample for extracting all keys and values, but without recursive.

```
with json_table as materialized (
    select 
        t2.pkey,
        t2.pvalue,   
        jsonb_typeof(t2.pvalue) as valuetype 
    from test.users t1 
    cross join jsonb_each(t1.json_text) t2(pkey, pvalue)
    where t1.id in (1,3,123)
)
select pkey, pvalue from json_table where valuetype not in ('object', 'array')
union all 
select t2.pkey, t2.pvalue from json_table t1
cross join jsonb_each(t1.pvalue) t2(pkey, pvalue)
where t1.valuetype in ('object')
union all 
select m2.pkey, m2.pvalue 
from 
    (
        select t1.pkey, t2.pvalue from json_table t1
        cross join jsonb_array_elements(t1.pvalue) t2(pvalue)
        where t1.valuetype in ('array')
    ) m1 
cross join jsonb_each(m1.pvalue) m2(pkey, pvalue);
```

**And result of this query:**

| pkey | pvalue |
| --- | --- |
| method_title | "POS Payment" |
| method_title | "POS Payment" |
| instructions | "" |
| method_title | "Cash On Delivery" |
| use | 1 |
| amount | "285" |
| use | 1 |
| amount | "5900" |
| method | "Debit Card" |
| details | "081958" |
| use | 1 |
| amount | "3245" |
| method | "Debit Card" |
| details | "379613" |
| use | 1 |
| amount | "649" |
| method | "Phonepe" |
| details | "2022040089 " |
| use | 1 |
| amount | "59" |
| method | "Phonepe" |
| details | "T22040584749376 " |